# vue babel-loader SyntaxError: Unexpected token on ":click" syntax

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jsx, vue-component, vue-loader

I use render function like this:

`.script.js`:

```
methods: {
    handleClick(data){
        console.log(data)
    },
    render(h, { node, data, store }) {
            return (
                <span>
                    <span>
                        <span>{node.label}</span>
                    </span>
                    <span style="float: right; margin-right: 20px">
                        <a href="javascript:;" 
                            :attr="data.id" @click="handleClick">Edit{data.id}
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </span>
            );
        }
}
```

But babel encoutners error saying the `:click` has Unexpected token.

`.vue`:

```
<template src="./template.html"></template>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

`package.json`:

```
"vue": "^2.2.6"
"vue-router": "^2.4.0"
"element-ui": "^1.2.8",
"babel-core": "^6.24.0",
"babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.4.2",
"vue-loader": "^11.3.4",
"webpack": "^2.3.1",
```

`webpack`:

```
{
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: `vue-loader`,
    options: {
        loaders: {
            js: 'babel-loader'
        }
    }
},
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: `babel-loader`,
    exclude: /(node_modules)/
}
```

`.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["es2015", { "modules": false }], "stage-1", "stage-2", "stage-3"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        ["transform-vue-jsx"],
        ["transform-object-assign"],
        ["component", [{
            "libraryName": "element-ui",
            "styleLibraryName": "theme-default"
        }]]
    ]
}
```

When i run `gulp dist`, babel throws an error like follows:

`Namespaced tags/attributes are not supported. JSX is not XML.\nFor attributes like xlink:href, use xlinkHref instead.`

Comment: Did you mean `@click`?

Comment: @thanksd i edited it.

Comment: That's not JSX. You can't intermingle JSX and Vue syntax; it's one or the other. It should be something like `onClick={this.handleClick}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bert Evans suggested,
after re-reading the reademe docs of https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx, I figured out that i just wrote the code without understanding the syntax of vue-specific jsx syntax.

As the docs says:

> Note that almost all built-in Vue directives are not supported when using JSX, the sole exception being `v-show`, which can be used with the `v-show={value}` syntax. In most cases there are obvious programmatic equivalents, for example `v-if` is just a ternary expression, and `v-for` is just an `array.map()` expression, etc.
>
> The equivalent of the above in Vue 2.0 JSX is:

```
render (h) {
      return (
        <div
          // normal attributes or component props.
          id="foo"
          // DOM properties are prefixed with `domProps`
          domPropsInnerHTML="bar"
          // event listeners are prefixed with `on` or `nativeOn`
          onClick={this.clickHandler}
          nativeOnClick={this.nativeClickHandler}
          // other special top-level properties
          class={{ foo: true, bar: false }}
          style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: '14px' }}
          key="key"
          ref="ref"
          // assign the `ref` is used on elements/components with v-for
          refInFor
          slot="slot">
        </div>
      )
    }
```

So, i changed my code to

```
render(h, {node,data,store}) {
    const link = {
        href: `/#/schema-type/${data.id}`
    };
    return (
        <span>
            <span>
                <span>{node.label}</span>
            </span>
            <span>
                <a href={link.href} target="_blank">edit</a>
            </span>
        </span>
    );
}
```

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your html as a string:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
    template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
});
```

It looks like you are used to React, but it write a little different.